# Selecting one drop down at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a gridview and each row has Drop down list, i want if user select value in one drop down then he may not select another drop down but if he selects then it should through error:

Sorry , you can select 1 value at a time

```
int count = 0;
    protected void ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //not used yet
    {
        count = count + 1;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        //int ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
        //short IsComplaint = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.SelectedValue);
        HiddenFieldIsValidDropDownValue.Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
        int RowID = Convert.ToInt16(HiddenFieldIsValidDropDownValue.Value);

        if (count >= 1) 
        {
            lblSelectionMessage.InnerText = count.ToString();
        }





}
```

Comment: change value of a label in this method and if label value is changed than show error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
               Label1.Text = "yes";
               protected void ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //not used yet
                {

               if(Label1.Text!="No")
                {                  
                  DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
                  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
                  //int ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
                  //short IsComplaint = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.SelectedValue);
                  HiddenFieldIsValidDropDownValue.Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
                  int RowID = Convert.ToInt16(HiddenFieldIsValidDropDownValue.Value);

                }
              else 
               {
                   lblSelectionMessage.InnerText = count.ToString();
               }
             }
```